# How to calculate a multiplication of two numbers which are in String variables?

Tags: java, android, types

```
String numberS = "1,332.0";
String numberE = "10";
    try {
      double value = Double.parseDouble(numberS) * Double.parseDouble(numberE);
      Log.d("result", String.valueOf(value));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { }
```

And then, I would like to know differences between `String.parseString()`, `String.valueOf()` & `toString()`.

Comment: parse them to numbers, multiply, print. Don't do this: catch (NumberFormatException e) { } though. How are you going to tell whether or not an Exception was thrown? anyway, since your code does exactly what you are trying to do .. what is the question again?

Comment: The toString() method returns the string representation of the object. The java string valueOf() method converts different types of values into string.

Comment: String.valueOf(Object) is basically just a null-safe invocation of toString() of the appropriate object.

Comment: `String.valueOf(Object)` is simply, as shown in the `String` class, `return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();`

Comment: 1,332.0 can never be converted to double just by Double.parseDouble(). You will have to remove any character other that . (dot) & integer before parsing to double.

Comment: `I would like to know differences` read the Javadoc. It explains what each method does. Please don't ask us to copy-paste what you can read yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you have to remove the comma(,) from string to convert or parse it in double or integer, otherwise it will give `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double` or invalid integer. You can remove the comma(,) as,

```
String newNumberS = numberS.replace(",",  "");
```

Above line convert `1,332.0` to `1332.0`. So, NumberFormatException solved. Now the whole working as,

```
String numberS = "1,332.0";
String numberE = "10";
     try {
         String newNumberS = numberS.replace(",",  "");
         double value = Double.parseDouble(nNumberS) * Double.parseDouble(numberE);
         log.i("tag", "value: "+value);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //catch exception here, if occur.
     }
```

**Now** about difference between `String.parseString()`, `String.valueOf(object)` and `Object.toString()`.

So simply if given `string` is null `String.valueOf(Object)` will prints NULL whereas `Object.toString()` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thx, I can solve the problem.